# I have a HTML site and Want to add simple dropdown menu like- Product 1 and Product 2

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Hi i have HTML site [http://sachmaasfoods.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and I want to add a deopdown in my main menu like-
Product

- Product 1
- Product 2

Please help me with the simplest css and html code. I don't want to show any background color, in main menu just dropdown in one small box.

I dtired some code from stackoverflow for they are showing a background in back I don't want back background

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the W3SCHOOLS CSS Dropdown tutorial? It can be seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

The first one shows elements on hover of other elements:

```html
 <style>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```